# Periodic orbits of generalized cat map near the origin

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, ds.dynamical-systems, hyperbolic-dynamics

Let $M\in SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ have eigenvalues $\lambda, \lambda^{-1}$ with $\lambda>1$., and suppose $M$ is diagonalized as $Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$ with $\det Q=1$. (Note that his doesn't determine $Q$, but it does bound $\|Q\|$ below). Let $M$ act on $\mathbb{T}^2=\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$. Here $M$ is a generalization of the famous [Arnol'd cat map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold%27s_cat_map), though we do *not* require that $M$ be symmetric.

It is easy to see that periodic points of $M$ are dense, and are in fact (by pigeonhole principle) precisely the points with rational coordinates. What I am concerned with are whole *periodic orbits*, and how far they must stray from the origin.

Specifically, it is not too hard to show that for any $M$ there is an $\epsilon$ such that there is no nontrivial periodic orbit fully contained in $B_{\epsilon}(0)$, where the ball is with respect to the usual distance on the torus. I have shown that we may take $\epsilon=\frac{c}{\lambda\|Q\|^2}$, for constant $c$ (in particular, $c=\frac{1}{4}$ works).

I have two questions:

1. **Is this well-known?** Is there some reference I can cite for this fact? I'm aware the cat map and its generalizations have been extensively studied, but I have difficulty navigating the classical dynamical systems literature.
2. **Is this sharp?** Is it true, say, that for all $c>0$ and $\delta_1, \delta_2$ not both $0$, there is an $M$ with a periodic orbit contained in $B_{\epsilon}(0)$ with $\epsilon=\frac{c}{\lambda^{1-\delta_1}\|Q\|^{2-\delta_2}}$? If not, what is the true bound?

Comment: I believe question 1 is well known. It follows from the shadowing lemma and the expansivity of Anosov diffeomorphism. However, I'm not sure about question 2. Maybe looking at the proof of those facts in these particular cases will give you some insights.